# Please help me bring this simple fluent nhibernate mapping to life

Tags: c#, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one

Well it all seems so simple and yet I can't find the answer to my problem.

Let's say I have 2 tables TableA and TableB that can hold a single reference to a 3rd table:

```
TableA       TableB        TableC
ID           ID            ID
TableC_ID    TableC_ID     RandomDataC
RandomDataA  RandomDataB
```

Each are represented by the following classes:

```
public Class ClassA{
  public virtual int Id{get;set;}
  public virtual ClassC ObjAC{get;set;}
  ...
}

public Class ClassB{
  public virtual int Id{get;set;}
  public virtual ClassC ObjBC{get;set;}
  ...
}

public Class ClassC{
  public virtual int Id{get;set;}
  ...
}
```

As you can see ClassA and ClassB hold a single property called ClassC.

I've tried the following mapping (amongst others...)

```
 public Class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>{
    public ClassAMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
       HasOne(x => x.ObjAC).Cascade.All();
       ...
    }
 }

 public Class ClassBMap : ClassMap<ClassB>{
    public ClassBMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
       HasOne(x => x.ObjBC).Cascade.All();
       ...
    }
 }

 public Class ClassCMap : ClassMap<ClassC>{
    public ClassCMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
    }
 }
```

but the mapping is incorrect. I've tried ClassCMap to have a ReferencesAny but without success.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>{
    public ClassAMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
       References(x => x.ObjAC, "TableC_ID").Cascade.All();
       ...
    }
 }

 public Class ClassBMap : ClassMap<ClassB>{
    public ClassBMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
       References(x => x.ObjBC, "TableC_ID").Cascade.All();
       ...
    }
 }

 public Class ClassCMap : ClassMap<ClassC>{
    public ClassCMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id);
    }
 }
```

You may also want to make sure the correct table names are being inferred. The issue is that HasOne maps to an entity based on the primary key of the table you're mapping from.

Answer (score 1):

When using a HasOne this implies that your table shares the same primary key with the other table. In your case this is not true.  Classes A, B, and C each have their own ids.  Check out the following article that explains this in more detail:

http://jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/

Answer (score 0):

You 're probably needing to use `References` instead of `HasOne`. HasOne has a unique use case.
Replace `HasOne` with `References`. I don't believe .Cascade.All() is necessary either.

You can check out the usage for HasOne here: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping.